# What would this inclined force equate to?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, torque

In the attached problem, i'm curious what effect, if any, the incline would have on the torque generated by the 50 kips force (shown below). Would it lead to a smaller/larger torque and, if so, why?  I think the incline wouldn't influence torque necessarily, since the angle between the applied force and the lever arm is 90 degrees, but i'm not 100% sure.

I appreciate any help or guidance anyone can offer on this matter.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The incline should not affect the torque. The torque of the 50 kips force (F) should be T = hxF, where h is distance AC. To calculate force of 60 kips force (F1) you will need to project the force vector outward so that it can form a line that is perpendicular from A to that point (supposing A is the pivot) if not is there more info for the question?.